# Checkbox that enables and disables Text field

Tags: text, input, checkbox

Problem is that i have lots of text fields(60-70 of them)

And i need to make that when checkbox is uncheked text input should be disabled and whenever checkbox is being checked text input is enabled.

And when checkbox is being uncheked it should disable the field and clean it.

Comment: What language/toolkit are you using?

Comment: If it's jquery write your code you want help with

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkbox').each(function(a,b){
   $(b).click(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).next('.textfield').removeAttribute('disabled');
      }else{
        $(this).next('.textfield').attr('disabled','disabled').val('');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: How to use it in Input fields?

Answer (score 0):

This using javascript can be done.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function textInput() {
        if (document.inputForm.checkbox.checked) {    
          document.inputForm.input.disabled=false;
        } else {
          document.inputForm.input.disabled=true;
        }
      }​
    </script>
    <form name="inputForm">
      <label>Enable Input</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="textInput()">
      <label> Input:</label>
      <input type="text" name="input" disabled="true">
     </form>
   </body>​​​​
</html>
```

Comment: It is kinda working, but i need textbos name for value send. any other ways?

Comment: @user2614879 what do u mean u need the textbox name for value send?

Comment: I Mean that my name = "Rights[]" and Rights[] is array i need to send to mysql

Comment: @user2614879 well i dont see a issue sending the name over in a form and also using javascript.